# How to simulate a simple keypress in Cypress

Tags: cypress

Working on webpage test automation with Cypress atm. Ran into a problem.

- I need to simulate a pressing of the ESCAPE key from a user.

Cypress has its own `type()` method, but it is required to chain off a DOM element, e.g. it has to be implemented this way:

```
cy.get(element).type('{esc}');
```

I want to simulate a simple key press of ESCAPE without involving any DOM element. Does anyone know how to do it?

I have tried

```
cy.get('body').type('{esc}');
```

which does not work.

Update:

I tried

```
cy.get('body').trigger('keydown', { keyCode: 27, which: 27 });//27 is the keycode for the escape key
```

Did not work either. I guess there is a mis-alignment between my expectation and Cypress specification.

- What I want to do is a simple key press from keyboard while Cypress has its `type()` to type into an element, they could be two different things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found an answer:

```
  cy.get('body').trigger('keydown', { keyCode: 27});
  cy.wait(500);
  cy.get('body').trigger('keyup', { keyCode: 27});
```

The amount of time cy.wait() waits is arbitrary. It depends on the application under test; but 200 mS seems to be working for me too.

Comment: As of april 2022 this no longer works. I think a jQuery solution would be more appropriate as explained by Gleb himself in a Youtube video.

Comment: @thednp Do you have a link to that YouTube video?  Or some more detail to help me search for it?

Comment: @MatthewWalker I can't remember the exact video, you might look for Gleb Bahmutov's channel on YT and search through his videos. You can also have a look at my color-picker Cypress tests on github, I managed to get it to work eventually, despite me saying it doesn't. The problem is always related to sync/async assertions, you might want to see what you do (ACTION and CONTEXT => assertion) before triggering events, assertions & actions can overlap, so you can also set separate `it()` for event assertions. Good luck.

Comment: I think the event has always some focus - it's just here you have to tell the focus explicitly... if you do not want any specific element focused, just use `body` or whatever. The call is, as some already answered, `cy.get(target).type(..., );`, however, what I was really looking for was how to keep the key pressed, you do so using **`{ release: false }`** as options param.

Comment: AFAICT this should now be `cy.get('body').trigger('keydown', { eventConstructor: "KeyboardEvent", keyCode: 27 })`, note the new field `eventConstructor`.

Answer (score 7):

The recommended command is:

```
cy.get('#someId').type('{esc}');
```

I'm using this to disclose pop-ups and where it makes sense to use ESCape as a User.

Cypress version: 8.3.0

Answer (score 4):

I was able to simulate native keypresses by utilizing the following repo: https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events

With the included `cy.realPress('Escape')` command it should work like a charm for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my application not all key codes are working - Home, End, ArrowUp, ArrowDown are not working. Only `cy.realPress('Tab')` and `cy.realPress('Enter')` triggered tab and Enter

Comment: I found alternative key values with the same keycode [here](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events/blob/main/src/keyCodeDefinitions.ts) e.g. `{downarrow}` for ArrowDown. Maybe try these otherwise I would suggest to open an issue on the github page to raise more awareness. Also check the version you are using :)

Comment: It's a good idea to report a but on the github page - with alternative keycodes `{downarrow}` or `{pagedown}`, it is not working also - not goes down

Answer (score 0):

The only real way to simulate a proper key event is to use this plugin:

https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events

And then you can only use that with Chrome. Other events will have 'isTrusted:false' which means several keyboard events won't be testable in Cypress the way they would be if manually tested.